# Defining a matrix as an array of arrays and computation its inverse matrix in C++

Tags: c++-cli

Unfortunately I haven't  much experience in C++ and I'm trying to progress myself in C++.

Firstly,I defined array of arrays so that I formed an 3x3 matrix:

```
array< array< double >^ >^ input = gcnew array< array< double >^ >(3);

for (j=0;j<input->Length;j++){
    input[j]=gcnew array<double>(3);
```

Then I assigned matrix elements to input array of arrays:

```
 int value=1;
for(y=0;y<(3);y++){
  for(x=0;x<(3);x++)
 {input[y][x]=value;
  value=value+1;
  }
  }
```

Is there a C++ function that compute inverse matrix of this input array of arrays?

Could you help me please?

Best Regards...

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Simple 3x3 matrix inverse code (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983999/simple-3x3-matrix-inverse-code-c).

Answer (score 0):

There are no functions in C++ to make matrix operations, you'll need to find some library to do it or implement your own.

Note that for fixed size arrays, you can use regular C/C++ arrays, like this one:

```
double arr[3][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a [list of numerical libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries) in various programming languages. If the functions that you are looking for are not available you could also consider writing a wrapper function around an available Fortran or C or C++ implementation.

Comment: I agree with this. There is a huge body of linear analysis code, much of it in Fortran, that will do what you want and there is no better place to start looking than Lapack on netlib.org.

I would also suggest not using the array of arrays paradigm. Most of the external code will expect the array to be a block of numbers suitably set up in row or column major order. Creating or finding a class with a suitable indexing operator should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There is not built in C++ function to do matrix inversion (or for any other matrix calculations).

There are **lots of methods for matrix inversion** mentioned [HERE.](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm)

If you want **efficiency and ease of implementation** then [Guassian Elimination](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm) is 
probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

Code for inverse of matrix using Elementary row transformation in c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
using
namespace std;

float a[4][4];float b[4][4]={{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}};
int no = 4;

int check(int k) {
    float cont = 0, cont2 = 0;
    for (int i = k; i < no; i++) {
        if (a[i][k] == 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < no; j++) {
                cont = a[i][j];
                cont2 = b[i][j];
                a[i][j] = a[k][j];
                b[i][j] = b[k][j];
                a[k][j] = cont;
                b[k][j] = cont2;
            }
        } else if (a[i][k] == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < no; j++) {
                cont = a[i][j];
                cont2 = b[i][j];
                a[i][j] = a[no - 1][j];
                b[i][j] = b[no - 1][j];
                a[no - 1][j] = cont;
                b[no - 1][j] = cont2;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int divi(int k) {
    float particular = a[k][k];
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        a[k][i] = a[k][i] / particular;
        b[k][i] = b[k][i] / particular;
        if (a[k][i] == (-0)) {
            a[k][i] = 0;
        }
        if (b[k][i] == (-0)) {
            b[k][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int sub1(int k) {
    float particular;
    for (int j = k + 1; j < no; j++) {
        particular = a[j][k];
        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
            a[j][i] = a[j][i] - (particular * a[k][i]);
            b[j][i] = b[j][i] - (particular * b[k][i]);
            if (a[j][i] == (-0)) {
                a[j][i] = 0;
            }
            if (b[j][i] == (-0)) {
                b[j][i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int sub2(int k) {
    float particular;
    for (int j = k - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        particular = a[j][k];
        for (int i = no - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            a[j][i] = a[j][i] - (particular * a[k][i]);
            b[j][i] = b[j][i] - (particular * b[k][i]);
            if (a[j][i] == (-0)) {
                a[j][i] = 0;
            }
            if (b[j][i] == (-0)) {
                b[j][i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int disp(){
 cout<<endl;
             for(int x=0;x<no;x++){
             for(int y=0;y<no;y++){
                   if(a[x][y]==(-0)){a[x][y]=0;}
                   if(b[x][y]==(-0)){b[x][y]=0;}
                   printf("%0.1f|||%0.1f     ",a[x][y],b[x][y]);
             }
             cout<<endl;}
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<no;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<no;j++){cout<<"Enter a["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]";cin>>a[i}[j];}
          }
    for(int i=0;i<no;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<no;j++){cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";}
    cout<<endl;
          }

    for(int i=0;i<no;i++){
        check(i);
            disp();
        divi(i);
            disp();
        sub1(i);
            disp();
    }
    for(int i=no-1;i>=0;i--){
     sub2(i);
     disp();
     cout<<endl;
     }
     getch();
     getch();
     getch();
 return 0;}

 }
```