# inverse of matrix in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Defining a matrix as an array of arrays and computation its inverse matrix in  C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868892/defining-a-matrix-as-an-array-of-arrays-and-computation-its-inverse-matrix-in-c)
>   [Simple 3x3 matrix inverse code (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983999/simple-3x3-matrix-inverse-code-c)

how to find a inverse of matrix in c++ . simple coding just to find inverse of 3by3 matrix and also for 4 by 4 matrix

Comment: Please show the code you have and why you suspect it isn't working. You should have more trouble understanding what the inverse of a matrix is and how to obtain it than to translate that thought into code, so it's obvious you aren't putting forth much effort here.

Comment: Duplicate - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983999/simple-3x3-matrix-inverse-code-c

Answer (score 10):

C++ provides no language facility to do this. You must either code it yourself or use a library.

If the question is how to code it, the starting place is "Do you know how to invert a matrix on paper?"

Comment: Great answer to the question given; not snarky, but makes a point.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question per se but rather a mathematical question.  Finding inverses of a matrix on a computer does, however, require ample knowledge that floating point arithmetic is flawed and imprecise.  If you don't believe me create a 3x3 array such that a_mn is 1/(m+n) and use the general inverse matrix solution you'd do on pen and paper.  You should go [here](http://www.nr.com/oldverswitcher.html) for all your simple math algorithms needs.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link to get inverse of the matrix , its very efficient method ( **Gauss Jordan** ) as 
compared to method based on co-factor and determinant.

Then think upon it and try to implement it yourself.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination